# UMVUE for $λ^{−\lambda}$ where $_1, _2$ are two independent observations from a Poisson$(λ)$ and $λ > 0$ is an unknown parameter.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, poisson-distribution

I am only familiar with finding UMVUE for $λ^{−\lambda}$ when $X_1,X_2,...,X_n \sim$ Poisson$(λ)$.

Where if $P(X=t)= \frac{e^{−\lambda}λ^{t}}{t!}$, I let $T = T(X) = I(X_1=t)$. Then $T$ is unbiased for $g(λ)$.

And since $∑X_i$ is a complete sufficient statistics for $λ$. $E(T|∑X_i)$ is UMVUE. The UMVUE is zero if $y=∑X_i<t$ and for $y \geq t$

\begin{align*}E(T|∑X_i=y) & = P(X_1=t|∑X_i=y) = \frac{P(X_1=t,∑X_i=y)}{P(∑X_i=y)} \\ & = 
    \frac{P(X_1=t)P(\sum_{I=2}^n X_i=y-t)}{{P(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=y)}} \\ &= 
   \frac{(e^{-\lambda} λ^t/t!)([(n-1)λ]^{y-t}e^{-(n-1)\lambda}/(y-t)!)}{(nλ)^ye^{-n\lambda}/y!} 
\\ &= \frac{y!}{t!(y-t)!} (n-1)^{y-t}n^{-y}.\end{align*}

Thus UMVUE of $λe^{-\lambda}$ is $$\left(\frac{Y}{n}\right)[(n-1)/n]^{Y-1}.$$

I was wondering how can I find the same UMVUE for $λe^{-\lambda}$ when $_1, _2$ are two independent observations from a Poisson$(λ)$.

It would be greatly appreciated for a solution.

Comment: please learn [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553).

Comment: I tried my best to edit it, sorry about that!

Comment: What are $g(\lambda)$ and $Y$?

Comment: Sorry Y is $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ and $g(\lambda)$ is simply (=)

Comment: You have found the solution for general $n$ and asking what happens when $n=2$?

Comment: If I input n=1, UMVUE is 0 and if I input n=2, UMVUE becomes $\frac{Y1^{Y-1}}{2^Y}$?

Comment: Thank you very much I think I understand now, Y should be X1+X2 which becomes Y/2^Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

$$T=\mathbb{1}_{\{1\}}(X_1)$$

$T$ is clearly unbiased for $\lambda e^{-\lambda}$ thus using Rao Blacwell and Lehmann Scheffé together you know that the UMVUE is

$$\mathbb{E}[T|X_1+X_2=s]$$

This conditional expectation can be easy calculated using the definition of Conditional probability

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[T|X_1+X_2=s] 
& =\mathbb{P}[T=1|X_1+X_2=s]\\
&=\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda}\mathbb{P}[X_2=s-1]}{\mathbb{P}[X_1+X_2=s]}\\
&= \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{s-1}}{(s-1)!}}{\frac{e^{-2\lambda}(2\lambda)^s}{s!}}\\
&=\frac{s!}{2^s(s-1)!}=\frac{s}{2^s}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand now!